# Animate items in css grid

Tags: html, css, animation, css-grid

I have a css grid. If I delete an item in grid, is there a way to animate other items to their position? By default they just fill empty space from deleted item instantly.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
  <div class="box e">E</div>
  <div class="box f">F</div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you open to use a library?

Comment: No this is not possible with CSS

Comment: I know I could use masonry for example. Is there a simpler solution with less code?